# Can electromagnetic wave function be entangled in two photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-entanglement

This might be a weird question, but this is what I’m saying.

If we entangle two photons, would it be possible to entangle not a characteristic like spin up or spin down but instead their individual electromagnetic waves?

If so how would you be able to read this or even do this.

If there is a way to do this, how would you read the first photon to find the second photon’s wave in that way? Because there are many, many possible waves not just up or down, so how would you read the first photon’s wave to figure out the wave of the second photon?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to ask can two photons be entangled in a single em wave function .... and they probably could be under special circumstances ... But in general the answer to your question is no.

Specifically a "wave function" is a mathematical description of an em state or sum of a number of states ... so we could adapt a wave function to describe almost any situation.

However with respect to entanglement we do know that the typical 2 photons created act completely independently of each other ..... i.e they can most correctly be described by 2 separate wave functions.  The only thing special about entanglement was that we knew the photons were created in opposite phase/spin .... this unfortunately led to a lot of misguided discussion about faster than light information.  We can measure one photon and know about the other .... but in no way does the measurement force the 2nd photon into another state.